# Gender package confidence factor in R

Tags: r, uncertainty

R's gender package is a great library to determine gender from first names. I know that the package predicts the gender by calculating the proportion of male and female names given a range of years.

From the predicted output, is there a way to determine the confidence of prediction?

A sample of the output is shown below:
The gender shown here is the predicted gender based on the proportion of male and female entries for that name in the SSA dataset.

```
            name proportion_male proportion_female gender year_min year_max
 2         LESLIE          0.2276            0.7724 female     1930     2012
 210        COREY          0.9502            0.0498   male     1930     2012
 3         KELSEY          0.0316            0.9684 female     1930     2012
 4          DARYL          0.9299            0.0701   male     1930     2012
```

Thanks,
B

Comment: The package does not compute confidence intervals. But note that you can access the underlying SSA dataset if you wish: `genderdata::ssa_national` and see `?genderdata::ssa_national`. But notice that there are problems with the data, which the function in the gender package try to deal with. https://github.com/ropensci/gender/issues/9

Comment: Thanks @LincolnMullen for responding. BTW, I'm getting an internal error executing the "genderize" method on the same data frame which worked with ssa and ipsum methods.  the exact error message is: Error in if (result$gender == "female") { : argument is of length zero - Looks like it is exiting when lookup the name "Priscian". Is there a place I can log it as a bug?

Comment: @Bee: Yes, please add a bug report here: https://github.com/ropensci/gender/issues. Thanks.

Comment: Why not bootstrap the confidence intervals?